# How to perform a Linq match on a single item without ToArray()

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is my XML file:

```
<items>
    <item>Apples</item>
    <item>Lemon</item>
    <item>Grapefruit</item>
</items>
```

And I am trying to find out whether any of the `<item>` in this XML list match the LAST item in my list below:

```
var titleList = new List<string> { "Pear", "Lime", "Lemon" };
```

at the moment I do it like this:

```
var itemMatch = Settings.xdoc.Root
    .Descendants("Items")
    .Where(test => titleList.Last().Contains((string)test.Element("Item")))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var item in itemMatch)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Element("item"));
}
```

But the foreach loop seems rather pointless as there will only ever be one match (Lemon in this case). How can I do this without the loop but still know which item has matched?

Comment: I am confused by the question; why would you call `ToArray` in the first place? If you don't want the unnecessary call to `ToArray` then why have you not simply removed it? Also it seems like the title of the question and the question you are asking are completely different. What are you actually asking here?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `FirstOrDefault` (or `First`) which by the way can be "merged" into `Where`:

```
var itemMatch = Settings.xdoc.Root
    .Descendants("Items")
    .FirstOrDefault(test => titleList.Last().Contains((string)test.Element("Item")));
```

This will give you the first element that matches the predicate or the default value (`null`) if no elements match. If you use `First` an exception is thrown if no element matches.

There are also `SingleOrDefault` and `Single` which will ensure that there is exactly one match (if there is a match). So if there are two or more matches an exception is thrown.

---

Your code doesn't work but here is a way to make it work based on the XML you have provided:

```
var titleList = new List<string> { "Pear", "Lime", "Lemon" };
var lastItemInList = titleList.Last();
var itemMatch = Settings.xdoc.Root
    .Elements("item")
    .FirstOrDefault(item => (string) item == lastItemInList)
```

Upon closer reading of this part of your question

> I am trying to find out whether any of the  in this XML list match the LAST item in my list

I get the impression that you just want to determine if the `<item>Lemon</item>` exists in the XML. In that case you can replace `FirstOrDefault` with `Any`. The return value will be a `bool` that indicates if the element was found.

---

Also, about `ToArray` which is in the title of your question: You don't need to call `ToArray` before enumerating the result using `foreach`. When you call `ToArray` the sequence is enumerated and stored in an array and it is the array that is enumerated in `foreach`. However, if you just want to enumerate the original sequence once there is no need to store it in an array so you can skip the call to `ToArray`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just what I needed.

Comment: Hang on. I thought it was working, but it only seems to be comparing the first item in the XML file against the last item in the titleList, not all items in the XML file.

It should be looking for "Lemon" from titleList.Last() in all <items>

Comment: @JamesNapier: I only answered your question about how to avoid the `foreach` loop when you knew that there was only a single result in the sequence. However, if I try to execute your code with the provided XML I get no results at all which isn't surprising as there seem to be a mismatch between the XML structure that your code expects and the XML structure you provide in the question. I will try to update my answer with an explanation how to fix that problem.